# Mockito when and thenReturn statement not working for 2 method calls in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermockito

Inside my Test class, I have the following mocking statement:

`when(metadata.getGranularity(message)).thenReturn(new Assembly.Partition.Builder.build());`

Basically, I am calling this above statement through two different test methods. One is existing and works fine, second is my newly written code which calls the same method. It's mentioned inside the setup method. It gets executed in both the cases and when I evaluate the value, it gives an object reference in both the cases, like this:

`result= {Assembly$Partition@3793}`

The code in my class that it is mocking is:

`Assembly.Partition granularity = metadata.getGranularity(message);`

But when the debugger goes from test method to the code, the builder creates an object reference in the first case i.e. `granularity= {Assembly$Partition@3892}`, but in the second case, it is giving the reference as null.

Also, sometimes while debugging, it gives me this debug error that Partition cannot be returned by toString().

### Edit

Existing test method is this:-

```
public void publish()
filePublisher.publishFirst(message, event, name);
verify(file publisher, times (1)).publishFile(anyString(), anyList(Mylist.class));
```

And my new method is:-

```
public void publish2()
filePublisher.publishSecond(date, id, type);
verify(file publisher, times (1)).publishFile(anyString(), anyList(Mylist.class));
```

Both methods compute various data to call the ***publishFile*** method.

Comment: can you share complete code of both the method junit and actual. possible reason may be parameter mocking not the same as expected

Comment: I have added the asked code

Comment: The issue is at the line Assembly.Partition granularity = metadata.getGranularity(message); where granularity is coming as null

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have not added enough (real) code to pin this down so don't expect a real answer! Here's a guess:

```
when(metadata.getGranularity(message))...
```

... only mocks when that exact `message` arrives. The `publish2` example is

```
filePublisher.publishSecond(date, id, type);
```

where `date != message`.

Try this:

```
when(metadata.getGranularity(any())).thenReturn(new Assembly.Partition.Builder.build());
```

Comment: Yes, that was the issue! Thanks a ton! Although, I was creating a separate message for my method, but I guess it wasn't working that way.